# defining and using styles in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, styles

i have created a derived class from telerik:RadGridView.
i need to styling the cells based on the data.
so that i have created a styling class and use it as cellstyleselector for columns.
i need to sett column cell style for each column and i used the below code but it does not work. do you have any idea of why it does not works?

```
        public WPFGridConv()
    {
        this.ShowGroupPanel = false;
        this.Loaded += WPFGridConv_Loaded;
        this.AutoGeneratingColumn += WPFGridConv_AutoGeneratingColumn;
        this.ValidationType = GridViewValidationType.None;
        this.ValidatesOnDataErrors= GridViewValidationMode.InViewMode;

    }

    private void WPFGridConv_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, GridViewAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateHeader();
    }


    public void WPFGridConv_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateHeader();

    }

    private void CreateHeader()
    {

        foreach (Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridViewColumn column in this.Columns)
        {

                column.CellStyleSelector= new GridStyleSelector();

        }
    }


public class GridStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (container is GridViewCell)
        {
            GridViewCell cell = container as GridViewCell;
            string columnId = cell.Column.Tag.ToString();
            WPFGridConv grid = cell.ParentOfType<WPFGridConv>();
            List<InputClass.GridColumnInfoClass> columnsInfoList = grid.workingGridClass.ListOfColumnsInfo;
            InputClass.GridColumnInfoClass columnInfo = columnsInfoList.Find(x => x.id == columnId);
            Type columnType = columnInfo.typeOfColumn;
            if ((cell.Value==null||string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Value.ToString())) && columnInfo.IsValueNecessary)
            {
                return NeedeValueStyle;
            }
            else
            {
                if (columnType == null || columnType == typeof(double))
                {
                    double dummyDbl;
                    if (!double.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out dummyDbl))
                        return BadInputStyle;
                    else
                        return CorrectValueStyle;
                }
                else if (columnType == typeof(int))
                {
                    int dummyInt;
                    if (!int.TryParse(cell.Value.ToString(), out dummyInt))
                        return BadInputStyle;
                    else
                        return CorrectValueStyle;
                }
                return CorrectValueStyle;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Style OutOfRangeStyle
    {
        get
        {
            Style returnStyle=new Style(typeof(GridViewCell));
            returnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(GridViewCell.BorderBrushProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple)));
            return returnStyle;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    public Style BadInputStyle {
        get
        {
            Style returnStyle = new Style(typeof(GridViewCell));
            returnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(GridViewCell.BorderBrushProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red)));
            return returnStyle;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    public Style NeedeValueStyle
    {
        get
        {
            Style returnStyle = new Style(typeof(GridViewCell));
            returnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(GridViewCell.BorderBrushProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.IndianRed)));
            return returnStyle;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
    public Style CorrectValueStyle
    {
        get
        {
            Style returnStyle = new Style(typeof(GridViewCell));
            returnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(GridViewCell.BorderBrushProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));
            return returnStyle;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi all and thank you for your responces. the telerik support answer me as below and as i examined, it was true.

> Hello,
>   The styles you defined are correctly defined and are indeed applied, however, because of RadGridView's gridlines, the BorderThickness and BorderBrush properties of the cell are not respected. You can test this by setting the Background or Foreground properties instead to see if the styles are applied.
>   Thus, you will need to edit the control template of the element in order to achieve the desired result. Here's a forum thread discussing a similar scenario.
>   I hope you find this helpful.
>   Regards,
>   Dilyan Traykov 
>   Telerik by Progress

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Implicit themes then your styles will not work because they are not based on the existing styles.

You should remove the styles you are creating in the getters, and instead add them as xaml resources in your app/page/control.

For example, change

```
    public Style CorrectValueStyle
{
    get
    {
        Style returnStyle = new Style(typeof(GridViewCell));
        returnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(GridViewCell.BorderBrushProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));
        return returnStyle;
    }
    set
    {

    }
}
```

to

```
    public Style CorrectValueStyle { get; set; }
```

and then in your xaml define the styleselector like this:

```
    <Grid.Resources>
    <my:GridStyleSelector x:Key="styleSelector">
        <my:GridStyleSelector.CorrectValueStyle>
            <Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            </Style>
        </my:GridStyleSelector.CorrectValueStyle>

        ...etc...

    </my:GridStyleSelector>
</Grid.Resources>
```

If you are using implicit themes then you will need to set the BasedOn property for each style:

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle">
```

You can then use your styleselector on a column like this:

```
<telerik:RadGridView>
<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding SomeProperty}"
                                CellStyleSelector="{StaticResource styleSelector}" />
</telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

Comment: hi and thank you for your responce. no i dont use implicit theme but also i dont have access to XAML of the class because i have created a class derived from the RadGridView to add some specification to it to use this new class as my grid views so that i dont have any XAML access of this class and i must define the styles in code also. what do you suggest?

Comment: Can you post your XAML code defining your GridView please?

Comment: because i have derived a class from a control class, i dont have any xaml file!